# Adding a HMHome with HomeKit

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I'm trying to add a Home to my HomeKitDemoApp. When i'm installing the app the first time on a device or simulator i'm getting the popup that HomeKitDemoApp like to access my accessory data.I press OK it seams to work and rooms are added to my tableview.
After i rebuild the app on the same device or simulator device i don't geht the rooms into my tableview. Now i get an error:

```
HomeKitDemoApp[22635:1632134] Add home error:Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=49 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HMErrorDomain error 49.)"
```

My code is:

```
    import Foundation
import UIKit
import HomeKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, HMHomeManagerDelegate{

    var homeManager:HMHomeManager = HMHomeManager()

    @IBOutlet var homesTableView: UITableView!

    var homes = [AnyObject]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }


    @IBAction func addHome(sender: AnyObject) {
        let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Zuhause hinzufügen", message: "Neues Zuhause zu HomeKit hinzufügen", preferredStyle: .Alert)


        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(nil)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction (title: "abbruch", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "hinzufügen", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:
            {
                (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                let textField = alert.textFields?[0] as UITextField

                //create home with the typed name
                    self.homeManager.addHomeWithName(textField.text, completionHandler:
                        {
                            (home: HMHome!,error )in
                            if let error = error {
                                NSLog("Add home error:\(error)")
                            }else{
                                println("im here in reloaddata")
                                self.homes.append(home)
                                self.homesTableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    )

        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomHomeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let home = self.homeManager.homes?[indexPath.row] as HMHome
        cell.textLabel?.text = home.name
        return cell

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return homes.count
    }
    // #pragma mark - HMHomeManager Delegate

    func homeManagerDidUpdateHomes(manager: HMHomeManager!) {

        self.homes = manager.homes

        self.homesTableView.reloadData()
    }

 }
```

hope anyone has an idea and can help me.
thank you.

Comment: HomeKit Error 49 resolves to `HMErrorCode.MaximumObjectLimitReached`, which is helpfully documented as "The maximum count of objects was reached." Take that for what you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum limit of adding home is 10.
Homekit will not allow to add more than 10 home.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have too many homes. I'm not sure what the limit is, but the homes are not removed when you rebuild the app. They (along with all other homekit data) persist in a shared database that is tied to an iCloud account.

How many homes did you create?

Answer (score 0):

HomeKit will allow to add a maximum of 10 homes. To delete all of the home data from your iOS device and iCloud, go to Settings > Privacy > HomeKit and tap "Reset HomeKit Configuration". Removing the app from the device and re-installing it will not clear the HomeKit Configuration.

hth